# Como somar horas php

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um sistema de banco de horas, onde tenho um caso em que um funcionário entra as 22:00hrs de um dia e sai as 07:00 do outro e gostaria de calcular a diferença entre esses horários, subitraindo o horario de intervalo! O resultado deveria ser 08:00 horas, porem esta saindo 21:00

O meu codigo esta assim :

```
$data1 = '21-03-2019';
$data2 = '22-03-2019';
$hora1 = '22:00';
$hora2 = '03:00';
$hora3 = '04:00';
$hora4 = '07:00';

$dateStart = new DateTime(''.$data1.''.$hora1.'');
$dateSai = new DateTime(''.$data2.''.$hora4.'');
$dateInter = new DateTime(''.$data2.''.$hora2.'');
$dateRet = new DateTime(''.$data2.''.$hora3.'');

$dateDiff = $dateStart->diff($dateSai);
$dateIntervalo = $dateInter->diff($dateRet);

if(strlen($dateDiff->h)<2)
{
    $horatrab1 = '0'.$dateDiff->h;
}
else
{
    $horatrab1 = $dateDiff->h;
}
if(strlen($dateDiff->i)<2)
{
    $mintrab1 = '0'.$dateDiff->i;
}
else
{
    $mintrab1 = $dateDiff->i;
}
echo $horastrabalhadas1 = $horatrab1 .":". $mintrab1. '<br />';

//intervalo
if(strlen($dateIntervalo->h)<2)
{
    $interhora = '0'.$dateIntervalo->h;
}
else
{
    $interhora = $dateIntervalo->h;
}
if(strlen($dateIntervalo->i)<2)
{
    $intermin = '0'.$dateIntervalo->i;
}
else
{
    $intermin = $dateIntervalo->i;
}
echo $intervalo = $interhora .":". $intermin. '<br />';


echo $horastrabalhadas = date('H:i', strtotime($horastrabalhadas1) - strtotime($intervalo));
```

Comment: Oi, olha isto: https://www.oyagum.com/articulos/sumar-restar-horas-minutos-segundos-php/, talvez seja de ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, eu achei mais simples calcular as horas totais separadamente do intervalo e depois realizar uma simples subtração das duas, segue exemplo:

```
$entrada = new DateTime('2019/03/22 22:30:00');
$saida = new DateTime('2019/03/23 07:07:00');

$diff_trabalhada = $entrada->diff($saida);
$horas_totais = ($diff_trabalhada->h * 60) + $diff_trabalhada->i; //quantidade de minutos entre a entrada e saída do funcionário na empresa

$saida_intervalo = new DateTime('2019/03/23 03:59:00');
$volta_intervalo = new DateTime('2019/03/23 04:05:00');

$diff_intervalo = $saida_intervalo->diff($volta_intervalo);
$horas_intervalo = ($diff_intervalo->h * 60) + $diff_intervalo->i; //quantidade de minutos do intervalo do funcionário

//subtraindo essas horas totais do intervalo temos a quantidade de horas trabalhadas
$horas_trabalhadas = $horas_totais - $horas_intervalo;
$horas = (int)($horas_trabalhadas/60); //horas inteiras trabalhadas
$minutos = $horas_trabalhadas % 60; //minutos trabalhados
echo "{$horas}:{$minutos}"; //concatenação entre os dois
```

Comment: Sim, mas no caso eu precisaria dos minutos e calcular o saldo extra caso o funcionário passe das 8 horas trabalhadas

Comment: @Edu Fiz as alterações adicionando os minutos

Comment: Valeu amigo, ajudou bastante!